# Any best practice for function objects

Tags: c++

Is there any best practice instantiating class objecs which has no data member (or minimal).

I mean, I have a class having a couple of common functions which can be widely used in many places in the code. So, I can,

- Instantiate that class at top in a class, pass that into other objects by reference and keep that reference in objects need that functions and call in methods using that reference.
- Instantiate that class at stack, call the method afterwards.
- Instantiate that class at every object which needs that function and call in methods using that object.

Because of the fact that those classes do not have data member, size of objects will be small, right?

Any ideas for common practice, performance for an embedded software and ease of maintenance?

Best Regards,
Burak

Answer (score 1):

If there's no members there's little reason for why you'd want to wrap it in a class. IMO it's a poor habit to wrap everything in classes just for the heck of it, classes are for objects. Putting it in a class communicates intent, and if you have no members at all you should instead keep it as a free function. We already have namespaces, so there's nothing wrong with either sticking it in child namespace if that makes sense, or simply having it as a free function in the namespace of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be the best practice to declare all the member functions as 'static', without any instantiation of the class.

For example:

```
class StringUtil {
  public:
    static std::string ToString(const AnyClass& target);
};

void f() {
    AnyClass a;
    std::cout << "a: " << StringUtil::ToString(a) << std::endl;
}
```